# Initialization of Biginteger in java

Tags: java, biginteger

I don't understand the meaning of `"" + 1` in the following initialization of `BigInteger` in Java:

```
BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("" + 1);
```

Comment: Same as `new BigInteger("1");`. Java uses `String.valueOf(1)`, creates an intermediate `StringBuilder` and makes that a `String`.

Comment: Its a shorthand for building string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lazy way of turning an Integer into a String.

```
""+1
```

is a concatenation of an empty String and the int 1, which is appended to the empty String, resulting in the String `"1"`.

You could also just write

```
BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("1");
```

Comment: I fail to see how `"" + 1` is lazier than `"1"`. It's at least a whole character longer...

Comment: Because I consider it a "I don't know any better" way of turning a number into a ``String``.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I take "lazy" as a replacement for something much less friendly.

Comment: @JamesKPolk. In a programming context "lazy" is already unfriendly enough :)

Comment: @f1sh why we can't just leave that parenthesis empty? Because in last every integer is gonna converted into a string.

Comment: @SiddharthVarshney because a BigInteger is supposed to represent a number and you have to provide one.

Comment: You could _also_ just write `BigInteger fact = BigInteger.ONE;`

Answer (score 3):

As is written in the docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

The BigInteger has a constructor that takes in a `String`. And when you declare an expression as `"" + 1` the type will evaluate to the first type from left to right, hence it will be a String.

Its literally the same as `new BigInteger("1")`

Why anyone would do this however apart trick students in class or people at job interviews is beyond me :)

Comment: It can come from simplifying code like "new BigInteger(""+n)" which isn't as horrible. I'm not sure that ((Integer)1).toString() is actually clearer for this type of demonstration.

Comment: @bko. Might be someone coding fast and doing it for variables, then momentarily forgot that you can stick the literal right into the string. Something like `"" + x` makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @BillK. The simpler "proper" way would be `String.valueOf(1)`, no?

Comment: Doing any sort of operation within a parameter parenthesis is super dirty imho, either move it one line up and declare an explicit cast to whichever type you may need and explicitly declare the type. 

Im not saying one way is better or worse, I'm saying they are all equally bad

And if i had to chose which i agree with @MadPhysicist that its better co call `String.valueOf(1)`. Why? You can read about in effective Java

Comment: The "" + x idiom isn't uncommon or slow.  I don't personally use it much but if someone who was used to it wanted to argue that it was more readable and showed clearer intent than a method call I wouldn't disagree too much.  It also handles nulls without throwing an exception which, depending on your purpose, can be better (like adding a quick log statement for debugging). Also you are already probably adding strings so it fits an existing pattern where a method call might break things.  System.out.println(""+lineNo+": "+lineData)   is probably clearer than the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a lazy way of turning an int into a string. It probably makes more sense when the int is a variable. Eg

```
public void doStuff(int i) {
    BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("" + i) ;
    ...
}
```

As others have pointed out there's other ways to achieve this but in this instance (when the int is a variable) its possibly the least characters